# Reading domino server' mailbox using C#

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am making an application which will retrieve all mailboxes from Domino Server.
And Display them in List.
After that i want to extract( display) emails of each mailbox into another list.

eg:
 Consider example of outlook.When we click on particular pst folder. all mails in selected folder get displayed.

Kindly send me code if possible.As i am new to C#.
Or send me related links.

Comment: If you have to read message contents and security polisy disallows the use of IMAP or POP3, please take look at this solution of fetching messages using http(s): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552141/how-to-fetch-message-body-and-attachments-in-xml-format-using-php-linux-from-lotu/2613189#2613189

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the simplest way to enumerate all the mailboxes without turning to Domino development is via LDAP. Then, as reto suggests, the IMAP interface should be able to show you the contents of each mailbox.

Of course, you'll need an account with access to each users mailbox.

Comment: Thanx Anders.

Can you suggest me some link where i can get some idea i.e how to list mailbox using  LDAP using C#.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using IMAP to fetch the necessary information. This should be easier than trying to use some Domino specific API. One of many [examples](http://www.example-code.com/csharp/imap_readMail.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Also [consider the COM library](http://www.bing.com/search?q=COM+Domino+server+createobject&form=QBRE&qs=n) for Domino.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at soapgate Q - that is a gen. werbservice gateway for domino - that would work for you:
[see the demo an soon view code](http://www.flexdomino.net/soapgateq)